# load an image from an url using opencv and cURL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, curl

I am trying to load an image from an url and display it.I am using opencv in c++ and cURL libraries.I am used to working with opencv,but I don't have any experience working with cURL libraries. I just need curl to load an image and save it in a cv::Mat file, so that I could display it. So, I took code from [here](https://gist.github.com/Benjit87/4188323/).It is supposed to be working,but I am getting syntax errors.
Also,I tried [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/91344/load-image-from-url/) code from opencv.org. But,I am getting same errors

Errors are
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';'

and about 90 syntax errors.When I click on errors it is opening cmath file and I cant find any syntax errors there.

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT 1:** I compiled the code as c++ and got rid of the above errors.Now I got a new error

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (buf.data && buf.isContinuous()) in cv::imdecode_, file ........\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp

Comment: This looks like a cascading syntax error, like a missing semi-colon somewhere in your code that's screwing up every line from then on. Can you post the code you're using, I couldn't see it in the link you left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling for `c` and not `c++`. Check two things:

1. Code file extension is `.cpp` and not `.c`.
2. Check the compilation properties:
   Tools bar -> Project -> Properties (or Alt + F7)->Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As: "Compile as C++ Code".

Comment: That solved the previous problem.Now, I am getting new error                          OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (buf.data && buf.isContinuous()) in cv::imdecode_, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp